# How to write an iOS Parse query that compares two fields in the same table?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nspredicate, pfquery

I have a parse table with 2 number fields and I need to create a query that pulls down only records where field2 is smaller than field1.

I tried this but it gives an exception that the predicate must have a key path and a constant:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"field2 < field1"];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:parseRequestObject predicate:predicate];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
    }

}];
```

Comment: Parse.com doc says "Simple comparisons such as =, !=, <, >, <=, >=, and BETWEEN with ***a key and a constant***." so I don't think you can directly do that. It expects something like @"field < 'value'". Try to ask the question on their forum, they're really active so you'll certainly get an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have just posted it on the Parse help. I assumed SO would have got me a quicker answer.

Comment: Sometimes it does, but in this case I believe you'll have more luck asking them directly. But maybe someone will have an answer here !

Comment: Looks like someone already asked this very question [on their forum](https://www.parse.com/questions/compare-object-fields-in-query), and the answer is you can't do it *yet*. They may include this if there is enough interest from the community. Definitely tell them you're interested too !

Comment: Thanks. A bit strange that it's not possible. So the only other way to do it would be to pull the whole table down and compare in my app?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way I see..

Comment: Thanks. I've got around it by using Parse cloud code to set a BOOL when 2=>1 so I can query the BOOL field to get what I need :)

Comment: That's a nice workaround. Maybe you could post some of your code as an answer if someone tries to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the only way to query this is to fetch all the data and compare on the device. However I managed to get around it using cloud code that sets a bool when `field2` becomes larger than `field1`. Now I can just query the BOOL field to get the records I need.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("MyObject", function(request, response) {
    var field1 = request.object.get("field1");
    var field2 = request.object.get("field2");

    if (field2 >= field1) {
        request.object.set("completed", true);
    }

    response.success();
});
```